# Give a proof by cases that $\lfloor 4x \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x+0.25 \rfloor + \lfloor x+0.5 \rfloor + \lfloor x+0.75 \rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Been stuck on this question for  a while, help would be appreciated! 
By the way,the square brackets are supposed to be floor brackets but I have no clue how to actually do those on a computer

Give a proof by cases that $\lfloor 4x\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor x+0.25\rfloor + \lfloor x+0.5\rfloor + \lfloor x+0.75\rfloor$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lfloor 4x\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor x+1/4\rfloor + \lfloor x+2/4\rfloor + \lfloor x+3/4\rfloor$$
First take $0\leq x <\frac{1}{4}$. We note that $\lfloor 4x\rfloor$ is greater than or equal to $0$ and less than $1$. As such, the LHS of the above is $0$. For the RHS we evaluate term by term. The first term is within $[0,\frac{1}{4})$, the second is within $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4})$, the third is within $[\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4})$, and the fourth is within $[\frac{3}{4},1)$. Since all are $\geq 0$ and all are less than $1$ the RHS must be zero as well. Now do the other three cases.

Comment: so 0=0 would be the proof for the first case? If I understood what you're saying, for the second case, the RHS would equal 0.25 and we would  have to show the left to be the same right?

Comment: Yes,  0=0 is a valid proof here. The second case will be $1/4 \leq x < 1/2$. Here we have that $1\leq 4x < 2$, so the floor of the LHS will equal $1$ and we want the right side to be the same. There are two other cases that are each $1/4$ apart, and then you need to show this covers all cases because the pattern is cyclic! The four cases should be enough for all $x$ :)

Comment: sounds good, thanks for getting me started!!

Answer (score 1):

@Cheesecracker: Use \lfloor and \rfloor in LaTeX environment.

Hint: Consider the fractional part of $x$, written $\{x\}$. You need four cases, one of which is $0\leq \{x\} <0.25$.

Comment: The first half of this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Good hint! Better than just giving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof
of a more general result
from another answer of mine.

If $n$ is a positive integer
then
$\lfloor nx \rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor  x+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor$.

Let
$m = \lfloor x \rfloor$
and
$d = x - m$,
so
$0 \le d < 1$.

Let
$j
=\lfloor nd \rfloor
$,
so
$0 \le j \le n-1
$
and
$\frac{j}{n}
\le d
< \frac{j+1}{n}
$.
If
$0 \le k \le n-j-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
m
&\le m+d+\frac{k}{n}\\
&< m+\frac{n-j}{n}+\frac{j}{n}\\
&= m+\frac{n}{n}\\
&= m+1\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor
=m
$.

If
$n-j \le k \le n-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
m+d+\frac{k}{n}
&\ge m+\frac{n-j}{n}+\frac{j}{n}\\
&= m+\frac{n}{n}\\
&= m+1\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
m+d+\frac{k}{n}
&\lt m+\frac{n-j+1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\\
&= m+\frac{2n-j}{n}\\
&= m+2-\frac{j}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor
=m+1
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor x+\frac{k}{n}  \rfloor
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n}  \rfloor\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-j-1} \lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor
+\sum_{k=n-j}^{n-1} \lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor\\
&= (n-j)m+j(m+1)\\
&= nm+j\\
\end{array}
$

and
$\lfloor nx \rfloor
=\lfloor n(m+d) \rfloor
=nm+\lfloor nd \rfloor
=nm+j
$.

We are done.